# Changing font size in drop down

Tags: html, css, html-select

I'm trying to style a form an some of the elements in my form are drop down menus. I am having trouble styling these items.

I have tried calling the select and then option like this

```
.writerBox select option{
  height:2em;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

and I have tried just calling the select. Is there something I'm missing here or a trick to make the font larger?

I have set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v82D8/1/) to play with. Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: I have looked at that and the answer was to create a div and then an ul list. If possible I would like to stick with the select menu. I have dynamic information coming in.

Comment: And you don't believe those answers because? :-)

Comment: "Unfortunately what you ask is not possible by using pure CSS."

Comment: I believe those answers, I was just hopping since that was posted two years ago that things had changed and this was now possible. Besides I have multiple...more then ten dynamic selects so to change them all would be a pain...and then fix them for mobile.

Comment: I happened to notice that the jsfiddle does not have any `font` or `font-size` in it.

Comment: Fair enough. The nice thing about SO is that popular questions are often updated with more recent solutions.

Comment: @Mr Lister: http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/487/

Comment: @MrLister No, that version does not. I was playing with it and no matter where I put a font or font-size nothing showed up. Apparently what I'm trying to do is impossible.

Comment: If you give both `select` and `option` a size, it works on many browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/v82D8/2/

Comment: @MrLister I just tested it in safari and chrome and on a phone and it's not working for me...

Comment: @zazvorniki Can you provide a screenshot of what it looks like for you? Here's mine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sX41n.png

Answer (score 0):

You can just set font-size of the select to a percent larger than 100

```
select{
    font-size: 130%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v82D8/3/)

Comment: this does not work with safari or chrome though

Comment: works in chrome because that is where I tested it

Comment: And it works in firefox and IE

Comment: I have been testing it in chrome and all it does on my end is move the select box a little to the right.

Comment: I think you may have some other issues then with your code... Can you elaborate on how you are using this? because it def works in all three of those browsers for me (using the jsfiddle)

Comment: I tested in Opera too and it works there as well. Under Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about changing the font of the select as a whole, this will do:

```
.writerBox select{ 
    font-size:60px;
}
```

Comment: this does not work in either safari or chrome though

Comment: There's something odd about your problem... This is supose to work in all browsers, as the answer above. Does this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/f3G2S/ ?

Comment: @zazvorniki - I just tested this in Chrome and it does, indeed, change the font size of the options, though it also changes the font size of the selected one (the one visible when the list is closed). Perhaps you're expecting a different behavior?